# What was the 1st Proof Assistant?

Tags: usage, history

What was the first proof assistant? What was it used for? When and by who was it created? Is it still used today? And what was its purpose?

Comment: Since computers and programs technically appeared *before* electric devices, the answer might probably be a little bit blurry...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Arguably, the first theorem prover was the [Logic Theorist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_Theorist), developed by a team at RAND back in the 1950s, which was used to generate alternate proofs for parts of Russell and Whitehead's *Principia*.

If you want to see what it looked like, I had a friend at RAND ask the archivist scan the July 12, 1956 revised version of the [P-868 technical report](https://github.com/pqnelson/blath/blob/master/P-868.pdf) which is 68 pages long (an earlier [draft](http://shelf1.library.cmu.edu/IMLS/MindModels/logictheorymachine.pdf) is online, too).

Russell wrote a short note to team, which was saved in the RAND archives:

[image]

> ## *Fan Mail...*
>
> Plas Penrhyn
> Penrhyndeudraeth
> Merioneth
>
> 2 November, 1956
>
> Dear Mr. Simon,
>
> Thank you for your letter of October 2 and for the very interesting enclosure (RAND P-868).
> I am delighted to know that *Principia Mathematica* can now be done by machinery.
> I wish Whitehead and I had known of this possibility before we both wasted ten years doing it by hand.
> I am quite willing to believe that everything in deductive logic can be done by a machine.
>
> Yours Very Truly,
> Bertrand Russell

Although it's not used anymore (it was written in assembly for the Johnniac), it inspired the Lisp programming language.

Comment: Perhaps add the year, which seems to be 1956.

Comment: I add the [original technical report](http://shelf1.library.cmu.edu/IMLS/MindModels/logictheorymachine.pdf); if someone wants to try to make a new version...

Answer (score 28):

The first (1968) fibrational proof assistant for computers is known to be [AUTOMATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automath) prover which was implemented under the lead of Nicolaas Govert de Bruijn (AUT-68). It's the direct ancestor of the "type theoretical" line of proof assistants from which the better known current ones are NuPRL and Coq. The last version is known to be [AUT-QE](https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/aut/aut-4.1-manual.pdf) and released under the lead of Freek Wiedijk.

Modern provers of that family nowadays usually use Calculus of Construction with full set of rules, while AUT-68 was using only $\star \leadsto \Box$, but was lacking $\Box \leadsto \Box$. So today we usually take PTS/CoC for educational purposes but not AUT-68.

If you want to feel the type system of proto-provers you should dive into [Henk: A Typed Intermediate Language](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2952858_Henk_A_Typed_Intermediate_Language) by Simon Peyton Jones and Erik Meijer. As for stable known implementations I would suggest [Morte](https://www.haskellforall.com/2014/09/morte-intermediate-language-for-super.html) for Haskell by Gabriella Gonzalez and its faster port to Erlang — [PTS$^\infty$](https://groupoid.space/pure/) by Groupoid.

As for non-fibrational provers in the style of Principia Mathematica (1910), you also can find a lot of implementations, and we also have one for educational purposes — [PRINCIPIA](https://principia.groupoid.space/), a logical system whose (almost) only inference rule is the substitution rule. It is insipired by Metamath and some Metamath-like systems.

Comment: What does "fibrational" mean?

Comment: In this context $\mathbf{dependently\ typed}$, a thing able to express $\star \leadsto \Box$ from Lambda Cube (the generalization of $\lambda$-calculi given by Henk Barendregt). So the first computer prover was dependently typed!

Comment: “Modern provers nowadays use Calculus of Construction” oh, the burn felt by the HOL and Isabelle users. I guess the line before that clarifies things, but maybe write “Modern provers of that family”

Comment: You have an objection that HOL/Isabell is not a modern prover? From usual udestanding for me e.g. Andromeda is modern, HOL is not. I just said like you said: from ‘that family’ $\mathbf{fibrational\ provers}$.

Comment: I concur with @JoachimBreitner, though I'm not a direct HOL user (in any of its flavours).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, all good :-)

Answer (score 13):

I regard "proof assistant" as synonymous with "interactive theorem prover", which rules out many of the systems mentioned in other answers. For example, the input to AUTOMATH was a deck of punched cards. AUTOMATH was a milestone but it was not a proof assistant.

I believe that the Boyer/Moore theorem prover was interactive from the start, though it may have supported a batch mode as well. Commands consisted of axioms, requests to prove particular formulas, and hints concerning rewriting. Boyer and Moore [published this work](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321864.321875) originally in 1975. And it continues to this day in the form of ACL2.

Another very early system was [Weyhrauch's FOL](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/77/432/CS-TR-77-432.pdf). It was an interactive proof checker for first-order logic. I never saw the point even back in the 1970s, since FOL is both inexpressive and easily automated.

The first recognisably modern proof assistant is undoubtedly [Edinburgh LCF](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-09724-4), which introduced the architecture on which most of today's proof assistants are closely based, especially those of the HOL family. Mike Gordon [traces the evolution here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/archive/mjcg/papers/HolHistory.pdf).